# why does this function object not need the specified?

Tags: c++

Could any one tell why this function object doesn't need the specified the type?

```
    class StringPtrTmplLess
{
public:
    template<typename PtrType>
    bool operator()(const PtrType * lhs, const PtrType * rhs)
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<string*, StringPtrTmplLess> s2;
    return 0;
}
```

how does the compiler know which specified type it will initialize the StringPtrTmplLess with?

Answer (score 3):

It is because of [template argument deduction](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_argument_deduction.htm) which means the template argument is *deduced* from the type of the argument passed to the function call. This type deduction is done by the compiler. Go through [the link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_argument_deduction.htm) which explains it in great detail.